# P5: Remove TableRows containing Null/NaN

Tags: java, processing

The aim is to return a clean table that only includes rows that have numeric data within them, from a nominated column. 
The code below works for me. But I can’t help but feel there is a better way to do this. Any thoughts on a more elegant solution?

I have the code:

```
Table removeEmptyRows(Table data, String column_name)
{
  IntList rows_to_remove = new IntList();
  Table dataCopy = cloneTable(data);

  for (int r = 0; r<dataCopy.getRowCount(); r++)
  {
    String value_string = dataCopy.getString(r, column_name);
    ///filter out the NaNs
    if ( ! isNullOrBlank(value_string))
    {
      if ( ! isNumeric(value_string) )
      {
        rows_to_remove.append(r);
      }
    } else {
      rows_to_remove.append(r);
    }
  }


  rows_to_remove.sortReverse();

  for (int r : rows_to_remove)
  {
    dataCopy.removeRow(r);
  }

  return dataCopy;
}

boolean isNumeric(String inputData) {
  return inputData.matches("[-+]?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");
}

private static boolean isNullOrBlank(String s)
{
  return (s==null || s.trim().equals(""));
}
```

Comment: What class is `Table` ?

Comment: It’s a Processing class

Comment: Without knowing the functionality of your classes, I'm not sure you can expect an optimal answer.

Comment: A valid point, but it is not my class. It’s a standard class in Processing.

Comment: I know this is a [tag:processing] question, but can you please post a [mcve] that shows us how you're loading the table (a sample file would help) and calling the `removeEmptyRows()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question might be a better fit at the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange (note that if you post there, please link between crossposts and make sure you post a true [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and make it clear that this is a Processing, not Java question), but I'll try to offer some input.

You can simplify your code by **adding good rows** instead of **removing bad rows**. Create the `returnTable` by copying just the columns from the `inputTable`, then loop over `inputTable` and only add the valid rows.

Also, take a look at this `if` statement:

```
if ( ! isNullOrBlank(value_string) ) {
    if ( ! isNumeric(value_string) ) {
        rows_to_remove.append(r);
    }
} 
else {
    rows_to_remove.append(r);
}
```

This will keep a row in one case: if the value is not `null` or blank and if it is numeric. You can rewrite this logic using a single `if` statement:

```
if (!isNullOrBlank(rowValue) && isNumeric(rowValue)){
```

Putting it all together, it looks like this:

```
Table removeEmptyRows(Table inputTable, String columnName){

  Table returnTable = cloneTable(inputTable);
  returnTable.clearRows();

  for (int row = 0; row < inputTable.getRowCount(); row++){
    String rowValue = inputTable.getString(row, columnName);

    if (!isNullOrBlank(rowValue) && isNumeric(rowValue)){
      returnTable.addRow(inputTable.getRow(row));
    }
  }

  return returnTable;

}
```

But note that this code isn't necessarily **better** than your code. It's not any faster. And if you understood your code, then that's the most important thing. If it works, don't worry too much about making it "more elegant". Just move on to the next thing.